# Python can't connect to MySQL db: OperationalError

Tags: python, mysql

When in the Python shell I type:

```
import MySQLdb
Con = MySQLdb.Connect(user='testuser', password='password', db='test')
```

And I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Nickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)
```

And no description of the error at all. Please, I am waiting for help. Thanks.

**UPDATE**: In case somebody will be having this problem, it appears to be connected with the new *mysql_auth_plugin*, with its new *Strong Password Encryption for Authentication*. I just switched to *old_password_plugin*(*Legacy Authentication Method*) in the configuration of MySQL Server and now [**All works!**].

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, `password` is not a keyword argument like you entered, instead it's `passwd` as you can see --> [here](http://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#mysqldb)

Comment: I have changed keyword argument to passwd and got the same result. Actually, if i type just `Con = MySQLdb.Connect()` without any argument I get the same OperationalError(2059, <NULL>)